# How to convert my absolute number into ascii numbers (preferably with no loop)?

Tags: java

I just want the program to get its absolute value, and print its corresponding character in the ASCII table. The reason for absolute value is for negative number inputs.

package Test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class asciiReader {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int num1, num2;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    num1 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
    
    int largestNum = Math.max(num1, num2); //scan who big num
    
    int absNum = Math.abs(largestNum);

    char ch = (char) absNum;
    int castAscii = (int) ch;

    System.out.println("Largest Number: " + absNum);
    System.out.println("The absolute Number is " + absNum);// display large num
    System.out.println("The ASCII value of "+ castAscii + "is: " + castAscii);
    
    
    
    
    
scan.close();
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since numbers appears orderly in the ascii table you can simply do this to get the char value of a number:

```
int absNum = Math.abs(largestNum);

char ch = absNum+'0';
int castAscii = (int) ch;
```

assuming `absNum` is one digit number , otherwise it can't be represented with `char`.